# When can you separate into two equations with common variable?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, recurrence-relations, systems-of-equations

It is given that $f(0) = 0, g(0) = 0$, and for integer $n > 0$, $f(n)\pi + g(n) = (\frac{f(n - 1)}{2} + 5)\pi + 3g(n-1) - 1$. Would it be correct to separate the part without $\pi$ and the part with $\pi$ similar to how it is done on imaginary and real part with $xi + y = ai + b \iff x = a \land y = b$ ? Like this:

$f(n)\pi + g(n) = (\frac{f(n - 1)}{2} + 5)\pi + 3g(n) - 1 \iff f(n)  =  \frac{f(n - 1)}{2} + 5 \land g(n) = 3g(n - 1) - 1$

And what would be the general property? Saying $ax + b = px + q \iff a = p \land b = q$ would not be the correct because for example $3(-5) + 2 = 2(-5) - 3 \iff 3 = 2 \land 2 = -3$ is not true

Comment: It sounds like you're just talking about equating coefficients.

Comment: At a first glance, I would say such a step is unjustified unless both $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ are guaranteed to be rational functions.

Comment: So what you're essentially asking is if this holds true $ad + b = cd + e$?

Comment: Suppose $f(n)=n/\pi$? This should show you why @Deepak's comment is important.